# NSIS Integration with Windows Games Explorer

Tags: installation, windows-vista, nsis

I'm trying to get the NSIS installer for my game to register the game with the Games Explorer in Vista/Win7.  In all other respects, my installer is working fine - but I've had a difficult time identifying the 'right' way to integrate with the Games explorer.  In my searching, I've found the following resources:

- [Game Explorer with Helper](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Game_Explorer_with_Helper)
- [Games Plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Games_plug-in)
- [Game Explorer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Game_explorer)

I've got the game-side tasks complete (my .EXE has embedded GDF resources), but the installer work is frustrating me. It seems that by now there should be a fairly well-honed approach to this, but none of these feel like 'it.'  Has anybody had experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) instead of NSIS?
Starting from version 3 it have pretty handy [Gaming Extension](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/22/new-wix-feature-gaming-extension/). ([schema](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/gaming_xsd_index.htm))

Comment: WiX is a better overall solution for sure, but I was too far down the road with NSIS at the time to switch over.

Answer (score 2):

There are solutions available for NSIS either [using the System plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Game_explorer) or with a [dedicated plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Games_plug-in).